# JavaFX. Changing instance variable from helper method for start method

Tags: java, javafx

everybody!

Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class QuestionClass extends Application {
    String labelText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuestionClass questionClass = new QuestionClass();
        questionClass.setLabelText(); 
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();

        // why string value wasn't assigned to string labelText in setLabelText()?
        System.out.println("labelText in start(): " + labelText); // OUTPUT: null

        label.setText(labelText);

        HBox pane = new HBox(label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void setLabelText() {
        labelText = "The Text";
        System.out.println("labelText in setLabelText(): " + labelText); // OUTPUT: The Text
    }

}
```

I have a problem with `String labelText` which is an instance variable. I expect that when I create an instance of a class `QuestionClass` and then I call a method `setLabelText()` on it, the variable `labelText` is changed to the value "The Text". Which is really so.

But after that I initialize building my JavaFX GUI by calling the method `launch(args)` and I expect my `labelText` variable to be already set to "The Text" value which sadly doesn't happen and the value of `labelText` is null.

The question is "Why?". Where is a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Because you are setting the value in a different instance of the Question class then the one that is being show to you

Comment: @SteelToe How is that possible? I have created only one instance `quesionClass`?

Comment: java created an instance allready, you dont need to create one yourself, rather you should use the instance that they created for you, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are setting the value of the label in a different instance of the QuestionClass then the one that is being shown to the user. The solution would to call the `setLabelText()` method in the start method on the current instance of QuestionClass so that it will refer to the current instance of your Question class.

So hange this part of your code from this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    QuestionClass questionClass = new QuestionClass();
    questionClass.setLabelText(); 
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Label label = new Label();

    // why string value wasn't assigned to string labelText in setLabelText()?
    System.out.println("labelText in start(): " + labelText); // OUTPUT: null

    label.setText(labelText);

    HBox pane = new HBox(label);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

To this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Label label = new Label();
    //this will call the method on the current instance of your Question class so it will work
    setLabelText();
    // why string value wasn't assigned to string labelText in setLabelText()?
    System.out.println("labelText in start(): " + labelText); // OUTPUT: null

    label.setText(labelText);

    HBox pane = new HBox(label);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Now it should work since it is being called on the current instance.

Comment: Thank you @SteelToe!  That worked! But I still don't understand how it is another instance of a class. The method `start()` belongs to `QuestionClass`. So does the method `setLabelText()`. And I create only one instance `questionClass`. Where is a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: in a javaFx application there is an Instanceo of the main class instantiated for you and that is the one that is shown to the user. And `setLabelText()` refers to an instance of QuestionClass and is differant for each instance, so calling it in the instance you created wont do anything in the instance that was created by java. Thats why it returned null cause you were calling it on your instance not the instance that was created for you